# Browser gets stuck/freeze with array push in angular 4. How to fix this?

Tags: node.js, angular, browser

I have an array in logsCompoment.ts named `logs` and I push new logs to this array and write logs in html page with ngFor.
I do this following ways.

```
this.socket.on('newline', (data) => {
                this.logs.push(data);
                }
            });
```

and in logsCompoment.html, I do following to show logs.

```
<li *ngFor="let log of logs" [innerHTML]="log"></li>
```

Everything works fine if logs are not coming very frequently. But if logs are coming very frequently like around 1000 lines in a seconds, it freezes the browser.
My question is, How to deal with such situations. If I am not following proper way to implement this, Please answer me with the proper way of its implementation, so that browser could not get stuck.

Comment: Each `log` contains HTML tags?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, Yes a few span tags to color text like WARNING, NOTICE etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a rxjs `Subject` with a `bufferTime()`. This would keep DOM updates to a consistent frequency.

---

Per OP's request, here is working example. I used `bufferTime()` instead of the previously suggested `debounce`

Here is a working example in [slackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmtb5n).
And a snippet of the actual code:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { scan, bufferTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent  {
  logs$ = new Subject();
  delayed$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor () {} 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.delayed$ = this.logs$
    .pipe(
      bufferTime(5000),
      scan((acc: string[], curr: string[]) => [...acc, ...curr], []),
    );

    // stand in code to replace OP's .socket() event listener
    const source = interval(100);
    source.subscribe(num => this.logs$.next(`<p>Log Item ${num}</p>`))
  }
}
```

Then in your html, you just need to subscribe. e.g.

```
<li *ngFor="let log of (delayed$ | async)" [innerHTML]="log"></li>
```

Comment: @joshvitoI think the above solution can solve my problem but currently its not working. so Can you please give me more clear example with all the imports required?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two ways to handle this problem.

One is to batch push items to array, but this will eventually freeze browser, as DOM tree will grow quickly.

Second option - much better is to implement thing called `virtual scroll`. Which will allow you to browse all the logs, but in the DOM there will be only few elements (the ones that are you currently seeing).

See this link for more info: https://netbasal.com/a-taste-of-angular-material-virtual-scroll-f173c5c70a1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DOM manipulation is *really* expensive. JavaScript is actually fast enough to handle large arrays, but for each new element added to the DOM, there is a really high likelihood that the page needs to be laid out from scratch. So even if you're just adding `<li>` tags, the browser needs to evaluate everything on the page to determine if its position should change.

Add a thousand rows a second, and there is now way it can ever keep up.

The best way is to implement some form of paging. You can keep your data in memory, but only put the ten or twenty most recent records on the page. You could even get away with a hundred, but just adding thousands of items will slow the page down even in general use.